# How can I change the perceived URL of my wordpress 404 page?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

If I navigate to `mysite.com/pageThatDNE`, I'd like my wordpress 404 template to load, but with the URL `mysite.com/error/404?m=myCustomMessage`. What is the best way to do that?

I tried using `wp_redirect` from the 404 page itself to a page called `error` which simply includes the 404 page. This works fine on my local WAMP setup, but I had issues moving to my server (the URL would change, but it gave me a `The requested URL /error/404 was not found on this server` error). [Another post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67291/using-wp-redirect-to-redirect-to-a-permalink) suggested that this is because `404` doesn't exist, but upon trying to create a child (of error) page called `404`, WP keeps renaming it to `404-2`.

How can I change the URL of my 404 page?

Comment: Do you have access to your server config files? There are multiple ways to do this.

Comment: I'd prefer to leave it in the theme so it's easier to move later (no special instructions)